# Is it good practice to use a pivot currency when converting currencies?

Tags: many-to-many, pivot, ssas, currency

In [microsoft's documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175660.aspx) they use a pivot currency exchange rate:

"The currency conversion functionality converts such transactions into the pivot currency, and then to one or more other reporting currencies."

But in [another article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/04/walkthrough-implement-many-to-many-currency-conversion-in-an-analysis-services-solution.aspx), they demo converting direct from any currency to any other currency (skipping the pivot).

Just curious as to why, in most documented examples, people use the pivot method - where as the non-pivot method seems less used? Is there any advantages/disadvantages of either?

Answer (score 1):

By using the pivot method you only need to keep track of the exchange rates for that one currency (to all other currencies), so if you handle `n` currencies, you have `n` exchange rates to track, rather than `n²-n`.

Storing all `n²-n` exchange rates is redundant data storage since you can get by with just `n` and calculate all currency exchanges using the pivot method.

Answer (score 0):

Most folk use a base or accounting currency.

That is, you'll have exchange rates against this (on my case CHF). So USDCHF, EURCHF etc. I had to do everything via CHF.

For 30 rates, you either use 30 pairs (includes CHFCHF) or all 900+ combinations precalculated (EURUSD and USDEUR)